# a two-dimensional vector

Tags: c#, winforms, vector, workflow-foundation, physics

I want to make a side scrolling game by C# windows forms, and for that I need to make a class for two-dimensional vectors. When searching the web all I found was 3 dimensional vectors which is way beyond what I need, and as soon as I add "two dimensional" to the query I get only results for multidimensional arrays.

All I need for the class to do is to be able to get a polaric expression of a vector (size and angle) and return it's cartesic expression (X,Y) & vice-versa. I tried doing it with Math.Sin and Math.Cos but I always get weird results. Can anyone help me with an explanation or a prepared code?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking `Math.Sin` and `Math.Cos` work with degrees; they actually work with radians. Otherwise it's pretty easy to roll your own `PolarCoordinate` class. I have one (with a bunch of other stuff) here that you could draw inspiration from I suppose: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126907/when-should-i-define-a-explicit-or-implicit-conversion-operator-in-c/12232002#12232002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Vector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.aspx) struct that is available in the `System.Windows` namespace. You can use it if you add reference to the **WindowsBase.dll**. Vector struct has numerous useful static methods but you can't get the angle of the Vector that simple. You could use `Vector.AngleBetween` for that purpose.